# Most elegant/correct spacing method for "/" with multi-word operands?

Tags: punctuation, spacing

Suppose one wants to give alternative single words around a slash, like: alpha/beta. This is simple, and the convention seems to be no spaces.

But what if one wishes to give something like "BBC"/"British Broadcasting Corporation"? Obviously the "s are extraneous and undesirable, but how else can one group the two operands of the '/' from the rest of the sentence?

Comment: Slashes aren't normally used in more [formal English](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/slash.html) (use "or"), and in informal English you can do what you like (bullet points are unambiguous). You don't normally use them to explain an abbreviation even in less formal texts - use brackets in your example "BBC (British Broadcasting Corporation)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to change anything? Consider:

> Add two teaspoons of corn starch or potato starch.
> Add two teaspoons of corn starch / potato starch.

If the sentence is perfectly understandable with "or", then why wouldn't it also be perfectly understandable with "/"? The "most elegant / correct spacing method" would therefore be to change nothing in most cases.

You write that "the convention seems to be no spaces", but that is far from universal. I often include a space on either side of a slash, and multi-word phrases are part of why I do so. (Another good reason is that it helps the phrase to break across lines; many text processors don't break at slashes without spaces.)

Of course, there can be problems, such as ambiguity. (For example: "You can offer cold soda / ice water to the guests." Is the choice between "cold soda" and "ice water" or between "soda" and "ice"?) If something like that is your concern, then please edit your question. It would also help to include a sample sentence.